# Consume all files in aws S3 where deleteAfterRead = false

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel

Is there a way to consume all the files in a S3 bucket without removing the files from S3 (in the S3, there are about 15,000 files)?

With the lag of **noop** parameter in aws-s3, the following configuration has a problem. And that problem is: it constantly retrieve the same 5 files over and over again.

```
    <endpoint id="fbPage" uri="aws-s3://bucket?amazonS3Client=#aws-credential&amp;deleteAfterRead=false&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=5&amp;prefix=dev/facebook/page"/>

    <route id="consumeS3FbPage">
        <from uri="ref:fbPage"/>
        <choice>
            <when>                  
                <simple>${header.CamelAwsS3ContentLength}  &gt; 0</simple> 
                <log message="Page File detected: ${header.CamelAwsS3Key}"/>
                <bean ref="dfaReportingRePull" method="s3toElasticFormat"/>

                <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
                    <constant>POST</constant>
                </setHeader>
                <to uri="http://localhost:9200/fb_camel/page/_bulk"/>
                <log message="Success"/>
            </when>
            <when>
                <simple>${header.CamelAwsS3ContentLength} == 0</simple>
                <log message="Empty content, Probably the s3 key Folder itself: ${header.CamelAwsS3Key}"/>
            </when>
        </choice>               
    </route>
```

The following log shows that the same file retrieved over and over again:

```
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:46,904 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Page File detected: dev/facebook/page/166866083481130/2014/05/31/9c9537e6-12a3-415e-aa3d-a450011008be.json
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:46,993 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Success
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:46,994 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Page File detected: dev/facebook/page/166866083481130/2014/06/01/97d85443-74af-4d64-9808-a4500110117a.json
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:47,002 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Success
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:47,002 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Page File detected: dev/facebook/page/166866083481130/2014/06/02/223410b2-b4ce-4b7f-8e47-a45001101254.json
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:47,010 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Success
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:47,011 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Page File detected: dev/facebook/page/166866083481130/2014/06/03/e5c21710-d764-453d-9736-a4500110132e.json
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:47,019 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Success
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:47,019 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Page File detected: dev/facebook/page/166866083481130/2014/06/04/851d3759-0c35-4679-838c-a4500110140b.json
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:47,027 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Success


[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:51,375 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Page File detected: dev/facebook/page/166866083481130/2014/05/31/9c9537e6-12a3-415e-aa3d-a450011008be.json
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:51,396 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Success
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:51,397 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Page File detected: dev/facebook/page/166866083481130/2014/06/01/97d85443-74af-4d64-9808-a4500110117a.json
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:51,409 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Success
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:51,410 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Page File detected: dev/facebook/page/166866083481130/2014/06/02/223410b2-b4ce-4b7f-8e47-a45001101254.json
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:51,419 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Success
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:51,420 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Page File detected: dev/facebook/page/166866083481130/2014/06/03/e5c21710-d764-453d-9736-a4500110132e.json
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:51,429 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Success
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:51,430 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Page File detected: dev/facebook/page/166866083481130/2014/06/04/851d3759-0c35-4679-838c-a4500110140b.json
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - aws-s3://bucket] 21:26:51,439 INFO  consumeS3FbPage - Success
```

Even if i use Idempotent, it simply detect that all the 5 files are duplicate, and hence ignored.

I wonder if i do deleteAfterRead, and put it back will work?  No, when i look at the code in http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/camel-aws-s3-get-only-files-I-need-td5714095.html , it seems the code only will loop through the list on the current return list from aws s3.

When i look at the code ListObjectsRequest.java, i see there is a way to define a marker, which indicate on which was the last processed s# key. Is there a way to get this market set via Camel Spring DSL? [Updated]No.

After drilling down the code, i found the root cause on why this is the case. And Is trackable via this JiRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8431

note: the Camel version is 2.14.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Apache Committer  Willem Jiang, the fix will be part of release 2.14.3. [Camel-8431](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8431)